# How to include the library "sound" into another class or library in processing?

Tags: java, processing

I am creating a class in processing. I need to play a particular sound, but I don't want to write the declaration of the library in the main program, I want to write that declaration inside de class. But it doesn't work.

I tried to change the position of the declaration inside the class, like in public variables, or outside the code for the class, but processing show me "it not exist the SoundFile(string,string) constructor"

//Inside the main program

```
thermalArray[] AMG88 = new thermalArray[1];//include the class
void setup()
{
  AMG88[0] = new thermalArray((int)(displayWidth * 0.1), (int)(displayHeight * 0.1), 255, 0, 80, 900, 200);
}
void draw()
{
}
```

//Inside the class

```
import processing.sound.*;

//OBJETOS DE LIBRERIAS
SoundFile O_D_3;
class thermalArray
{
  //CONSTRUCTOR
  thermalArray(float xPos_, float yPos_, int color_base_r_, int color_base_g_, int color_base_b_, float _W, float _H)
  {
    O_D_3 = new SoundFile(this, "ok.wav");//hear it the problem 
  }
}
```